# Optimize python code with return in the code

Tags: python

I want to optimize my code to return well in a part of a code.

I know that I can do that with do while but I think it's maybe heavy with a lot of do while.

I identify where I want to return in comments

Can you suggest me a solution to solve my problem?

```
#return here 0
mainMenu()
choix = input()

if choix == 1:
    print "Enter your username"
    username = raw_input()
    print "Enter your password"
    password = raw_input()
    createAccount.createAccount(username,password)
    #return here 1
    educatorMenu()

    choix = input()

    if choix == 1: 
        print "Enter his age"
        ageChild = raw_input()
        print "Enter his photo"
        photoChild = raw_input()
        educator.createChildAccount(ageChild, photoChild)

    elif choix == 2:
        childrenList = educator.seeChildrenList()
        #Return to where it is written "return here 0"

    elif choix == 3:
        childrenList = educator.seeChildrenList()
        print "Associate children?"
        choixEnfant = input()
        educator.associateChildren(childrenList,choixEnfant-1, educator.getIdEducator(username))
        #Return to where it is written "return here 1"
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Optimize, the indentation is wrong, I would be surprised if this compiles.

Comment: I edit the question. Sorry it's a bad copy-paste

Comment: but there is nothing here that for instance loops. etc. So that means optimization should be done in the functions called by this code, not this code itself.

Comment: Have you read what I want to do and see comments on my code? I know that I can add do while loops but it's not too heavy?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I will not re-write/optimize your code, because I feel it should be a task for you to do so. Furthermore, there are quite some functions and references missing to rewrite it; you did not deliver an *MWE*.

Consequently, you may find this useful as a starting point and try to adapt this (*very* basic structure) to suit your needs. However, **be warned**: This also is far from being efficient, but it will help you to extend your knowledge of the basics.

```
def menu_main():
    q = ['What would you like to do?', 
         '1: List educators',
         '2: Create educator',
         '3: Manage educator\'s children',
         '4: Exit'].join('\n  ')
    return int(input(q).strip()[0])

def menu_educator_create():
    usr = input('Enter username:').strip()
    pwd = input('Enter password:').strip()
    return (usr, pwd)

def menu_educator_manage():
    q = ['What would you like to do?', 
         '1: List children',
         '2: Add child',
         '3: Return'].join('\n  ')
    return int(input(q).strip()[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edus = {}

    exit = False
    while not exit:
        print('===')
        cmd = menu_main()

        if cmd == 1:
            # List educators
            pass
        elif cmd == 2:
            # Create educator
            usr, pwd = menu_educator_create()
            pass
        elif cmd == 3:
            # Manage children
            # (should somehow obtain current educator first)
            exit_edu = False
            while not exit_edu:
                subcmd = menu_educator_manage()
                if subcmd == 1:
                    # List children
                    pass
                elif subcmd == 2:
                    # Add child
                    pass
                elif subcmd == 3:
                    # Return
                    exit_edu = True
                else:
                    # None of the above
                    print('Unknown choice from educator menu.')
        elif cmd == 4:
            # Exit
            exit = True
        else:
            # None of the above
            print('Unknown choice from main menu.')
```